# How to use Server Controls with PostBack with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postback, servercontrols

Once I click the button, it throws a "Validation of viewstate MAC failed" exception. I know MVC does not support PostBack but is there any way to work around this?

Or we need to use HtmlHelper in MVC?

Below is my code in View:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<form id="form1" runat="server">

<h2>Hello World</h2>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<br />
<br />

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

</form>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't fight your framework - if you want to use ASP.NET MVC, then go ahead and use it but [create controls using the tools of the framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx).

If you want or need to use postback controls then you really ought to stick with regular old ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

http://somewebguy.wordpress.com/2009/07/27/webcontrols-in-mvc-part-1/

http://somewebguy.wordpress.com/2009/08/07/webcontrols-in-mvc-part-2/

http://somewebguy.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/using-webcontrols-in-mvc-part-3/